# Using HTML and CSS to make an animated parking lot grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new to CSS and HTMl, and I'm trying to create this graphic on my website that displays whether or not a parking space is filled. I want the graphic to be top down, and I'm having trouble making this because I want each spot to change colors based on the data set from SQL.

I can't seem to find a tool that would allow me to create the graphic then animate it to put on my website. I was wondering if anyone had a starting point or a tool I could use to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any tool available that just builds projects for you.  With some fairly intro-level knowledge of html/css, and mysql, you should be able to make this happen.  I'd suggest just start working on it, and come here when you have a more specific question.

Comment: As a basic starting point, you will likely want either a `table`, or a grid of `div`s, which you can color by modifying their background in Javascript, based on your data which you retrieve using your server side language (personally I like Ruby on Rails, but recommend PHP for your first project), by calling your server script from the Javascript using Ajax. I'm not sure what your experience level is, but that should hopefully give you at least enough basis to start googling for the information and tutorials you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with HTML using various DIVs to map out the spaces then add a CSS class to the spots you want to visually indicate are taken/empty.

However if your parking spaces get even slightly off perfectly orthogonal rectangles, you'll likely find that an SVG based map of parking spots where each spot is a PATH element will be even better.

In either case just add/remove CSS classes from each spot to indicate it's status.

E.g. Give each spot an ID of "spot_123" (adjust the number part to suit) then when you want to set a status on the spot add a class.

```
.available{
  background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, you've given me a good place to start from